# Teaching integration to kids

Tags: calculus, integration, education

I have been selected by my college to teach integration to kids in the age group of 8-12. I am an engineering major who has finished Calculus 1 and 2 but I have no idea how to teach integration from scratch to kids that small and at the same time make it fun for them. I am asked to create a lesson plan, worksheets, manipulatives etc.

Any help is appreciated. Parents or teachers, your ideas will really come handy.

Comment: Do they know differentiation?

Comment: No thats actually the trick. I am told to teach them integration yet they havent done differetiation yet...

Comment: Teaching an 8 year old integration!!! Good luck man.

Comment: Go through a rigorous definition of the Lebesgue Integral.

Comment: I am a girl....but thanks!

Comment: Basically I want them to understand the concept and not know the entire thing.

Comment: **You are doing an almost impossible task.** Most of these kids haven't even mastered their algebra, yet they are going to learn the beginnings of Calc 2. If I were you, I wouldn't bother with computations what so ever. They don't know Derivatives so teaching anti-derivatives is hard. And taking integrals without knowing anything about summations is a nightmare. I would just focus on some elementary physics and show them applications, but not go in depth in anything at all.

Comment: @MadelynShroeder: You might want to consider something graphical, for example: http://www.intmath.com/integration/riemann-sums.php

Comment: @idiot I think https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tgyr42ezjq is better because you can make your own function and don't have to use their built in functions that they give you

Comment: Well, if we want to compare these, I would use a CAS to give you all the functionality that those provides. There are many tools one can use.

Comment: @idiot Agreed, CAS will give you all the functionality you would need.

Comment: Try http://matheducators.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @JamesSmith: This one is also decent and allows flexibility (I think Wolfram Alpha has a similar one): http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannSum.html

Comment: @idiot Yes that is also pretty good. BTW: That queries wolfram alpha, so wolfram alpha would give the same thing. I think it inputs "Riemann sum of {FUNCTION} as x goes from {LEFTPOINT} to {RIGHTPOINT}". It may have addition parameters, but it gets its information from wolfram alpha.

Comment: @idiot webmathematica and Wolfram Alpha are both part of Wolfram the company.

Comment: @idiot They also have mathematica which is a very powerful CAS based system!

Comment: Is there a reason that you have to teach integration?  It seems like there are a lot of very cool, enriching math topics that would be more realistic to do with that age group.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily go for area under the curve. I might start with a brief bit about derivatives giving rate of change and then explain how integrals are the reverse, i.e., finding where something has been based on where it started (or ended) and how fast it went.

Comment: I remember my learning of calculus was greatly helped by seeing plots of position, velocity, and acceleration (in particular, by discussing the performance of a model rocket using such plots) - one can see both the derivative and integral (as inverses to each other) doing this (though no one ever made reference to them). It also side-steps the things that make calculus hard; there's no reason you must explain to students why one needs to define "area under a curve" when it is, after all, possible to see, nor is there need to go into integration techniques (or differentiation formulae).

Comment: How much time will you have in class with the kids?

Comment: @mickep I think their elementary level of math is a much bigger issue than time. There is absolutely no way of teaching a 5th grader integration without teaching them about the coordinate axis, lines, parabolas, summations, and basic algebra first. Calculus has to be thought from the ground up. And they shouldn't be forced to learn such a high level of math without knowing what $5^2$ even means.

Comment: @mickep And if you don't teach calc from the ground up it will just be a sea of unrelated concepts. The students will memorize rules, but not understand them. They will inevitably apply them when they can't be applied and grow to hate math when all these rules get mixed up in their brains.

Comment: @paw88789 That is exactly what I am wondering.

Comment: This would be better on matheducators.SE and also, why are you doing this? No one can benefit from this.

Comment: ?!?!  This is all you were asked to do: teach integration?  Are you being evaluated on how well you do?  If so, on what basis are you being evaluated?  If there's no basis for evaluation, what does it even mean to teach integration to ten-year-olds?  Unless they are prodigiously talented, there's almost no hope of teaching it to them symbolically, so a basic notion of what it enables seems to me all that you can convey.  (Just to clarify: I'm not criticizing you, only what you are being expected to do.  It seems utterly unrealistic at first blush.)

Comment: I would say this is ... Dumb... By whoever asked you to this .

Comment: @MadelynShroeder You asked this question several years ago. Can you edit the question to tell us what happened?

Answer (score 12):

First, your task is impossible to teach rigorously. Since these students probably don't have the algebra skills necessary to set the groundwork to success in calculus. But this is what I would do as my lesson plan.

First define what area even means in terms of area of a rectangle. The area of a rectangle is $length*width$ or $a*b$.

[image]

Next show areas are additive and show other areas.
So the area of a triangle is $\frac{1}{2}a\cdot b$.
[image]
**But WHY?** Well explain to them area is additive and show them this is what the area of a triangle has to be, to be consistent with the area of a rectangle.
[image]
Then provide as many proofs as you want to show that Area of A + Area of B=Area of A & B.

I would also stick to geometric ways of showing most of my ideas.

Also show how rectangle A, $1\:\cdot \:2$, has the same area as rectange B, $\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{2}$.

[image]

And as a geometric way to help them understand so you can cut one rectangle to achieve the other rectangle, reinforcing areas can be subtracted and added.

[image]

Anyway, once you have them interested in the idea that area that if two things have the same area you can geometrically chop one thing into pieces and form the other thing; then introduces curves. This idea of area being able to cut pieces and rearrange it to form another thing with the same area is totally destroyed with objects with curved boundaries.

For example what does it mean to have an area of $\pi $.Well then teach them that they can find area in terms of rectangles which they already know.
[image]
Show them they can approximate by making small enough rectangles. Obviously we don't care to much about computations as much as giving them a general understanding, so I wouldn't go overboard with it. I wouldn't introduce limits directly, but make sure they understand the smaller the rectangles the better approximation they get.

Now at this point I finally start talking about curves and introduce some notation. I start with a simple curve and partition it into rectangles.
[image]

I say $dx$ represents the width of the tiny rectangle, $f(x)$ is the height, $\int $ is sum of, and $b$ and $a$ is my interval. I am not getting technical whatsoever to what these actually represent! Not defining limits, not going into summations, anti-derivatives or the fundamental theorem.

Show them something like $\int _0^1x^2dx=\frac{1}{3}$ and ask them what $\int _0^13x^2dx$

[image]

Finally teach them about how they can approximate areas of some small curves.

I would use desmos online graphing calculator to show them the how to use rectangular area approximations.

[image]

Comment: Great up to the point where you started writing out functions and integration notation. At that point you will lose almost your entire audience. Skip functions and variable relations beyond $Area = a \times b$. Even the concept of coordinate axes is likely to be entirely new to some of them. I would suggest not bothering with them and just discussing it as "find the area of the circle on this side of the line", and similar.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Children at 8 may lack the concept of square root and may be uncomfortable with fractions, so I would say great up to the rectangle, then half of the audience is gone already :(

Comment: @PaulSinclair To be fair, the question asked how to teach integration. So, my response had to have something building up to integration. So I thought this was the easiest way of doing so. BUT I totally agree with you! 5th graders simply don't have the math skills required to learn calculus in a short amount of time. If the coordinate axis is new to them, then this is an **impossible and unreasonable task** that she has been assigned to do!

Comment: @DarioP Yeah, you have a **good point**. Calculus was **difficult for me in high school**. Now if I had to learn integration in 5th grade, **I would have hated math**! Learning integration without learning limits is very **unintuitive**. But teaching limits will be a complete **waste of time** because they are still grasping the concept of what a line in the form of $y=ax+b$ even means. They likely haven't heard of the coordinate plane yet. I do think they learn fractions in 3rd grade. I am pretty sure it is part of the common core curriculum.

Comment: Wow is all I have to say.

Comment: I agree that to teach full *integration* is ridiculous. But you started off with something simpler, that kids can understand and can lead them to the right direction: area can be approximated with rectangles, and you can make that approximation as good as you like. You can even teach them that this is how the area of a shape is defined. These are concepts that kids can grasp if presented right. That is why I said you were doing great, up until you brought in the integral notation (except for the square root, which also should be avoided).

Answer (score 3):

This may not answer your question. But it will probably be a good response. DON'T TEACH CALCULUS to kids! I suggest you teach them something more enriching and realistic like paw88789 said. There isn't a need for these kids to learn calculus at such a young age. Calculus can be very confusing and complex, they should wait till they mature a little bit.

> I have been selected by my college to teach integration to kids in the
>   age group of 8-12.

Go to who ever selected you to teach calculus and explain to them how unrealistic his or her goal is to accomplish. Is there a reason why they want you to teach calculus to these kids?

> I am an engineering major who has finished Calculus 1 and 2 but I have no idea how to teach integration from scratch to
>   kids that small

You shouldn't have an idea on how to teach it. Some of these kids won't know the multiplication table, how are you going to teach them calculus? The answer is you wont.

> and at the same time make it fun for them.

Teach them about something they can understand. And that applies to them in nature. Something they can talk about with their friends. Or just be an easy going teacher. Maybe make some math jokes. But stay away from calculus. Not that calculus can't be fun, but they can't understand it or apply it.

> I am asked
>   to create a lesson plan, worksheets, manipulatives etc.
>   Any help is appreciated. Parents/Teachers, your ideas will really come
>   handy.

If you really can't avoid teaching them something more useful or passing on the offer. Then teach them about slopes instead. Then show them the bare bones concept of derivatives. But stay away from integration and anti-differentiation. Anti-differentiation is like anti-multiplying or factoring, it requires a lot more skill. Derivatives itself are a huge stretch, but is a whole lot more reasonable of a task than integration. Ideally stay away from calculus altogether.

Most of these kids are not going to be math majors and have no purpose for learning calculus especially at that young of an age.

Comment: This should be the accepted "response." It doesn't answer the question, but it is what the OP should consider.

Answer (score 2):

Define integration as area under a curve.

Use examples to approximate well-known areas (start with line, e.g. area of trapezoid, and make it more complex like semi-circle or half-ellipse or parabola) with rectangles and see the numbers getting closer to what the area is.

You cannot teach analytic integration because they won't be able to find the anti-derivative, so stay in geometric approximations. Not sure you can do much else at that age.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any specific advice, but I remember hearing about a book that was really good; [Calculus for Young People](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/096216741X). Maybe you could get in contact with the author as well?

Comment: WOAH, That book was written for kids 7 and up and it looks pretty good. I just saw the preview though

Comment: Here is a comment I read on this book, "This is an outstanding book because it takes the mumbo-jumbo out of traditionally taught calculus and makes the ideas accessible to ANYONE, not just to math whizzes. The technical vocabulary and symbolic notation can always be learned later. This book introduces the important ideas of calculus with simple, natural language and, most helpful of all, illuminating graphics, so the beauty (yes, beauty) and fun of calculus comes through.  This book is FUN, and it makes calculus FUN!"

Comment: Ok, I know I am responding to this question a lot, but I look at a pdf of the book. It is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

The furthest you can teach them before having to explain derivatives is [Riemann Sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum). This gives them the geometric intuition behind the integral, but does not give a useful method of evaluating integrals analytically.  You could just tell them that
$$\int_a^bx^n\,dx=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(b^{n+1}-a^{n+1}\right)$$ 
and have them check by using Riemann sums to see if the formula gives the correct area. But I'm not a fan of telling kids to use certain formulas without proving that they work, because then they'll feel that mathematics is just memorizing formulas.

As for making the learning process fun, you could frame your integration problems by using physics. Give them polynomials for the velocity of a race car as a function of time and ask them to determine who would win a race after a given amount of time. If they don't understand the relationship between velocity and displacement, you could explain that to them.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, when I first was introduced to calculus, I was introduced of it in terms of physics. I didn't even know what a limit was. I think instead of over complementing them you should make it as graphical as you possibly can. Teach them basic physics, so they can relate the math to the world around them. Come up with good word problems that would make sense to the students. I don't have a concrete lesson plan for you like some of the other answers. BUT, here is a video series that I thought was pretty good. You should obviously go much slower and simplify the videos. Also turn it into word problems. Don't focus on computations, focus on insight in how these ideas explain physics.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXGjJSMZGDA

Note: I didn't post this video onto youtube. So if this answer is useful, let the credit go to the poster of the video.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an exact answer because I honestly don't know what I would do if someone told me I had to teach little kids calc, however I have a book that may lead you in the right direction. It is called "*The Cartoon Guide to Calculus*" by Larry Gonick.

Answer (score 0):

When I was doing this with the kids I would lay out a grid and draw the figure on 1/2" plywood... then we'd physically cut out the area under the curve and weigh it compared with a known "area" (a 2x2 inch square---whose weight over 4 is the weight per unit square or density

voila...

Answer (score 0):

Like many comments and answers here indicate it is impossible to teach integration (and in fact any calculus concept) to students of age 8-12 years. Any efforts to do this will be wasted because the students at this age don't have the basic knowledge of alagebra/trigonometry which is essential to study calculus.

My own encounter with calculus started at age of 13 with some crappy textbook (most calculus textbooks fall in this category) and I did know trigonometry at that time so was able to learn mechanical differentiation and integration. But then I had no idea whatsoever about what these concepts meant and I could not do any problem which was based on application of these concepts. And interestingly I could not handle evaluation of limits and derivatives using limit definition.

In my opinion it is better to teach students of age 11-12 something which is at the very heart of "foundations of calculus". And that is the appreciation of order relations between rational numbers and more importantly density of rationals. This is something that can be grasped easily by a student who knows how to do $+, -, \times, /$ with fractions. But unfortunately this aspect of density is never emphasized when dealing with fractions. When we were studying rational numbers at the age of 12 years we did get some exercises like "find 10 rationals between $1/2$ and $2/3$" but it was based on a general algebraic procedure to find $n$ equally spaced numbers between $a, b$. Even more interesting was the technique of expressing the numbers in decimals and then find the intermediate numbers by changing some decimal digits.

It is also better to let the students appreciate the simple fact that *there is no least positive rational number*. And such facts form the backbone of typical arguments used in analysis proofs. This also helps the students to deal with the notions of *infinitely small* and *infinity*. And if students are taught this part well, they can be presented with the Dedekind's theory of real numbers at age 16-17 just before they start to learn calculus.

I was lucky enough to follow this route to calculus with Hardy's *A Course of Pure Mathematics*. However proceeding in this fashion has a side effect of wiping out almost 30-40 percent of ungraduate real analysis and that is probably one reason this particular approach to calculus is not followed.

Comment: If you're going to talk about infinitely small then it seems it would also be necessary to talk about the Archimedean property as well, that is, that there is _no_ infinitely small real number that is not zero. Also, one other _peeve_ I have is the introduction of infinite decimals so soon. Which leads to weird stuff like people thinking 0.99999... != 1 and these notions being remarkably hard to expunge from their thinking. Because they don't have a proper understanding of the real numbers. IMO, infinite decimals should be BANISHED from the pre-calculus math curriculum. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) Just say that some numbers cannot be represented exactly with a decimal, but must be approximated. 1/3 is not "0.33333...." rather it's 1/3, which can be approximated with 0.3, 0.33, 0.33333, etc. by adding however many threes you like. Infinite decimals are, after all, infinite sums, so they should not be introduced until there is the machinery to make sense of infinite sums _properly_ . This probably can't be done with any current crop of students as they've already been "poisoned" almost surely, but for the next generations.

Comment: In this sense 1/3 is not also different from $\sqrt{2}$, either, it's just that there is no simple pattern to generate better approximations. 1.41, 1.4142, etc. but no simple pattern.

Comment: PS. Wiping out 30-40% of undergrad real analysis is a GOOD thing, that frees up more time to teach other stuff.

Comment: @mike4ty4: I fully agree with your views. They are spot on the topic under discussion and I am glad you added these comments for the benefit for everyone here.

Answer (score 0):

For children of this age, you're probably better off introducing integration as 
a method to compute averages. The problem with the traditional approach is that this builds on a lot of math that the children have not yet been exposed to. Any attempt to go down the traditional part would end up being very boring to most of the children. We can circumvent that problem by exploiting the fact that today's children are fluent in using their smartphones and computers. In their free time, they take pictures, record videos which they share with each other on social media.

One can hook into their experiences to introduce integration, by giving them assignments like taking pictures and analyzing the pictures using programs like [ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/). A picture magnified sufficiently becomes a set of gray values. The children can be taught about noise, e.g. they can be let to stumble into that when given the assignment to enhance contrast allowing them to peek into a dark areas. Stretching the gray values will look like a magical method to see things that were invisible in the original picture, but we now get a lot more noise. So, what is noise and how can we get rid of that? Thing is that the children will be very motivated to understand all of this.

Simple methods to reduce noise involve taking local averages can be taught. When the children do this they also see that such manipulations come with unwanted side effects. One can then ask how a picture  viewed on a a large scale where it has smoothly changing gray value, changes when we take such averages. So, integration pops up quite naturally within this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I am writting from Hungary, sorry for the language mistakes.
I think also, we can not teach any concepts of calculus for Young children, but we can speak with them about infinity small, infinity big numbers, about change, area, approximate calculation, estimation.
After playing and understanding mathematics idea, children can make some problems of calculus, and also they can understand what are the differences beetwen knowing calculus and knowing just $f'(x)$ in the case of $f(x)= x^n$.

Comment: Does x ad n mean x+n?

Comment: Not, it does not mean. It means exponentiation.